# Sqlldr loader number column import

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-loader

Below is the my raw file

```
br-Name-acc-Bal
10 B    LO  1,000.12-
10 C    SB  2,000.15
11 D    FD  5,000.00
12 E    RD  6,000.00
14 G    LO  8,000.56-
15 Q    LO  7,000.89-
```

I want to import these data into my table using sqlldr and I need (-) symbol front of the bal column without (,) comma.

---

```
load data
infile *
truncate into table table1
fields 
trailing nullcols
(
Br    POSITION(1:2) ,
Name POSITION(4:5),
acc POSITION(6:7) ,
bal POSITION(10:18) ----->What should I mention here??? (Here am using datatype as number(17,3))
)

begindata
```

---

I am looking for the result like below

[image]

Could you please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

For data you posted, it would look like this: take substring of the `BAL` value up to 8 characters in length and multiply it by `-1` if the 9th character is `-`.

Target table:

```
SQL> desc table1
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- ---------------------
 BR                                                             VARCHAR2(10)
 NAME                                                           VARCHAR2(10)
 ACC                                                            VARCHAR2(10)
 BAL                                                            NUMBER
```

Control file:

```
load data
infile *
truncate into table table1
fields 
trailing nullcols
(
Br    POSITION(1:2),
Name  POSITION(4:5),
acc   POSITION(6:7),
bal   POSITION(10:18) "to_number(substr(:bal, 1, 8), '9g999d99', 'nls_numeric_characters = .,') * 
                       case when substr(:bal, -1) = '-' then -1 else 1 end"
)

begindata
10 B LO  1,000.12-
10 C SB  2,000.15
11 D FD  5,000.00
12 E RD  6,000.00
14 G LO  8,000.56-
15 Q LO  7,000.89-
```

Loading session & result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@kc11gt control=test35.ctl log=test35.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Sri O×u 24 12:24:59 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 5
Commit point reached - logical record count 6

SQL> select * from table1;

        BR NAME       ACC               BAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10 B          LO           -1000,12
        10 C          SB            2000,15
        11 D          FD               5000
        12 E          RD               6000
        14 G          LO           -8000,56
        15 Q          LO           -7000,89

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

There are no decimals displayed for 5000 and 6000 because it is the `NUMBER` datatype column; if you want to see decimals, either use `TO_CHAR` function with appropriate format mask or (if tool you use allows it) set numeric format, such as in SQL*Plus

```
SQL> set numformat 9999d99
SQL> select * from table1;

BR         NAME       ACC             BAL
---------- ---------- ---------- --------
10         B          LO         -1000,12
10         C          SB          2000,15
11         D          FD          5000,00
12         E          RD          6000,00
14         G          LO         -8000,56
15         Q          LO         -7000,89
```

Comment: Actually my original amount column is more than 8 char, what can I mention instead of '9g999d99'. Amt column data type is varchar2(25). Sample amount                                       
 1.    22,43,000.00                                                                                                                    
 2.    22,43,000.00-                                                                                                                   
 3. 4,2,24,3000.00

Comment: You have a problem, then, if you don't know how will data look like. Your best option is to make sure that input data looks absolutely valid. Negative numbers should begin with a "minus" sign, and there shouldn't be any format applied to numbers (except decimals, if they exist).